# abelian variety used like module

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

I am reading Hida's "p-adic automorphic forms on Shimura varieties",
p99, toward the end of the page, $A$ is an abelian variety, and $O$ an endormorphism ring, $O \to End(A)$, $c^{-1}$ is an ideal, he uses a sequence $0 \to O \to c \to c/O \to 0$ and tensor with $A$ to get $0 \to Tor_1(c/O,A) \to A \to A \otimes_O c \to 0$, he refer to his book
LFE 1.1, but the referenced section deals with modules, i understand the sequence if $A$ is module, but what is the meaning of the object $A \otimes_O c$ and $Tor_1(c/o,A)$ when $A$ is abelian variety? is there any reference?

Comment: $A$ is an $O$-module, isn't it?

Comment: Tangential, but what is $c$ and is $c$ and $C$ the same? You can [edit] the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a base ring $B$, the category of schemes over $B$ can be identified as a covariant functor from the category $\textbf{B-Alg}$ of $B$-algebras into the category $\textbf{Sets}$ of sets. In other words, the category of schemes over $B$ is isomorphic to the full subcategory of covariant functors from $\textbf{B-Alg}$ nto $\textbf{Sets}$, Grothendieck's viewpoint; see Section 4 of notes from a graduate course of Hida [here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~hida/207b.1.12w/Lec12w.pdf) (or Section 4.1 of another Springer book of his published in 2013 [here](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4614-6657-4)).

Hida, Haruzo. **Elliptic curves and arithmetic invariants**.  Springer Monographs in Mathematics. *Springer*, *New York*, 2013. xviii+449 pp.

For example, this goes as follows, if $B$ is a field and $X$ is a variety over $B$, for any $B$-algebras $K$, one associates the set of $K$-rational points $X(K)$ of $X$; so, we get a covariant functor $K \mapsto X(K)$. If $A$ is an abelian variety whose endomorphism algebra containing $O$, $A(K)$ is an abelian group and actually an $O$-module (so, the functor has values in the category of $O$-modules). Thus if $M$ is an $O$-module, one can think of a new covariant functor $K \mapsto A(K) \otimes_O M$. If $M$ is finite type over $O$ as modules and $O$-flat, long ago, Serre showed that there exists an abelian variety $A'$ such that $A'(K)$ is isomorphic to $A(K) \otimes_O M$ for all $K$. This abelian variety $A'$; is the one written $A \otimes_O M$. Similarly $\text{Tor}_1^O(A, \mathfrak{c}/O)$ is a functor from $B$-algebras into finite abelian group sending $K$ to $\text{Tor}_1^O(A(K), \mathfrak{c}/O)$ which is again represented by a finite flat group subscheme of $A$. Thus $A \otimes_O \mathfrak{c}$ is the quotient of $A$ by a finite torsion subgroup. If $B$ is a field of characteristic $0$, as is well known (from the time of Weil) the quotient of an abelian variety over $B$ by a torsion subgroup is again an abelian variety (proving classically Serre's result in this special case).